# JQuery on submit show dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

First sorry for my bad English.

I would like to show a confirmation layer (id="confirmwin") before submitting a form (id="form"). There is another button (id="yes") to submit the form.

I tried this:

Layer:

```
<div id="confirmwin" style="display:none">
Are you sure to submit?<br>
<a href="#" id="yes">Yes</a> <a href="#" onclick="closeconfirmwin()">No</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yes").click( function() {
    $("#form").off("submit").submit();
  });
  $("#form").on("submit", function() {
    $('#confirmwin').show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Sometimes (not always) it looks like it's in an endless loop.

Perhaps the #yes click event's off event goes wrong.

Comment: What did you try so far to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `.submit()` while turning it off?

```
$("#form").off("submit").submit();
```

shouldn't it be..

```
$("#form").off("submit")  //if
```

and only if confirmed proceed to do..

```
$("#form").submit(); //then you can /off() but I don't see the need to
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to pass extra parameters while triggering the submit event.
You can read more about event data in [the jQuery API here](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

```
$("#yes").click( function() {
    $("#form").trigger("submit", [true]);
});

$("#form").on("submit", function(e, blnConfirmed) {
    // If it's not confirmed yet, show the overlay.
    if (!blnConfirmed) {
        $('#confirmwin').show();
        return false;
    } // else it actually IS confirmed, do a real submit
});
```

You should test this code first. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy:

Just add an global var:

```
var ignoreConfirm = false;
```

so it will look like:

```
$("#yes").click( function() {
  ignoreConfirm = true;
  $("#form").off("submit").submit();
});

$("#form").on("submit", function() {
  if(!ignoreConfirm){
   $('#confirmwin').show();
   return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

simples as this

```
<form id="xpto" name="" action="" ... onsubmit="return callJavascriptFunctionConfirm();">

//bla bla bla here

</form>

function callJavascriptFunctionConfirm(){
   //do the logic here
   if (yes) 
      return true; 
   else
      return false;
}
```

}